# How to convert QVariant to QJsonValue?

Tags: c++, qt, qjson

How to convert `QVariant` to `QJsonValue`?
I know `QVariant` provide the `toJsonValue` function, but it did not perform as expected.

For example:

```
qDebug()<<QVariant(1.0).toJsonValue();
qDebug()<<QVariant("test").toJsonValue();
```

Both return:

```
QJsonValue(null)
QJsonValue(null)
```

Expect output:

```
QJsonValue(double, 1)
QJsonValue(string, "test")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this static function too:

```
QJsonValue::fromVariant( myVariant )
```

Check [this link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#fromVariant) for more info.

Comment: This does the desired conversion, unlike `QVariant::toJsonValue`

Answer (score 0):

You might do the following:

```
QVariant dblVariant(1.0);
QVariant strVariant("test");

QJsonValue dblJs(dblVariant.toDouble());
QJsonValue strJs(strVariant.toString());
```

Your approach doesn't work because variant object should have user type `QJsonValue`, but it doesn't. Therefore it returns default constructed `QJsonValue` object.

Comment: I thought Qt should be "smarter", able to detect the data type.

Comment: There is nothing about being smart in this case. If you have value `1.0` it's impossible to say whether it meant to be a double or QJsonValue unless you explicitly specify the type of the variant. If you need to let Qt know that QVariant stores QJsonValue you have to construct QVariant out of QJsonValue with `QVariant::QVariant(const QJsonValue &val)`. In that case `toJsonValue()` will work properly.